# How to check if a document exists in a collection in Firestore using Document ID?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin

I want to check whether a particular document is present in a collection in Firestore using Document ID.

Collection is **Users**

I have the Doucment ID of an user.

Just want to know whether the user is already present in the USERS collection

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `exists()` method, like this:

```
Firebase.firestore.collection("Users").document(id).get().addOnSuccessListener {
            if(it.exists())
            {
                //do stuff
            }
        }
```